# How to remove 1 column from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, unique

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("past.csv", index_col=0)

town_unique= df[['town']].drop_duplicates()
print('List of towns:', town_unique)
```

*The output turn out to be this:*

```
List of towns:                     
                  **town
month**                   
**2017-01**       ANG MO KIO

**2017-01**            BEDOK

**2017-01**           BISHAN

**2017-01**      BUKIT BATOK

**2017-01**      BUKIT MERAH

**2017-01**    BUKIT PANJANG
```

I have managed to sort out the unique town in the file. But how do I remove those in bold?? month is column O and town is column 1.

The desired output is:

List of towns:

ANG MO KIO

BEDOK

BISHAN

BUKIT BATOK

Answer (score 0):

Collect all the months you want to remove in a list and then filter that list out with `~`

```
month_list = [....]

df[~df[month].isin(month_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(town_unique.reset_index(drop=true))
```

Assuming the first column is index, the above api call will drop the index and you will be able get an integer based index with the list of names.

Or

```
print(town_unique['town'].to_list())
```

will only get you the list of towns.